# What is the name of this pattern? (answer: Remote Proxy)

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, proxy-pattern

Consider a class `OriginalClass` that might or might not be available on runtime. `OriginalClass` has a method `doSomething` which should be executed if its class is available.

A way of solving this is creating a class that also has a `doSomething` method that calls the `OriginalClass.doSomething` using reflection. Something like this:

```
public class CompatibilityClass {

    private static Method originalClass_doSomething = null;

    static {
        initCompatibility();
    };

    private static void initCompatibility() {
        try {
            originalClass_doSomething = Class.forName("originalClass").getMethod("doSomething", new Class[] {});
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {}
    }

    public static void doSomething() {
        if (originalClass_doSomething != null) {
            try {
                originalClass_doSomething.invoke(null, new Object[]{});
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }

}
```

What is the name of the design pattern applied here? I suspect it's either **Adapter**, **Bridge**, **Facade** or **Proxy**, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: The answer goes in the answer field, not the question title field. Geez.

Comment: It's a way to make the title more useful. If not there's no way to differentiate this question from the other "What is the name of this pattern?" questions. Geez. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's the [**proxy pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

You've create a proxy class that wraps the gory reflection stuff and delegates the method call to a different object.

> *A proxy, in its most general form, is a class functioning as an interface to something else. The proxy could interface to anything: a network connection, a large object in memory, a file, or some other resource that is expensive or impossible to duplicate.*

You pattern is quite similar to something like performing some method call over a network.

Comment: And what kind of Proxy would that be? A Remote Proxy, even if the original class is not exactly "remote"? http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javapedia/ProxyPattern

Comment: I agree.You are creating a proxy.

Comment: @hgpc, yeah. A remote proxy is probably the best match of those four. Just as in this situation though, I've seen proxies that doesn't really fit any of those four categories.

Comment: @hgpc: As an example, I [implemented the observer pattern](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/java-generic-observer/) using a proxy. The call is proxied to all listeners. No idea how such a proxy would be called. ;p

Answer (score 2):

Smells like proxy to me. But aren't you better off using [Java's default Dynamic Proxy API](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2000/jw-1110-proxy.html)?

Definition of proxy:

> A proxy forces object method calls to
>   occur indirectly through the proxy
>   object, which acts as a surrogate or
>   delegate for the underlying object
>   being proxied. Proxy objects are
>   usually declared so that the client
>   objects have no indication that they
>   have a proxy object instance.

Comment: How would Dynamic Proxy API work with static methods, though?

Comment: @hgpc: You'll have to verify this, but as far as I remember the proxy works through an interface. Where you delegate the calls to doesn't matter, static or instance methods ...

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation:

- **Adapter**: when you have two classes (A and B) that are semantically equivalent/similar, but have different interfaces. Adapter implements interface of A but delegates to B or vice-versa so A and B can be used interchangeably
- **Bridge** - typically used with whole inheritance tree (I never used it though)
- **Facade** - hide complexity of one or more classes behind simpler interface
- **Proxy** - same interface as the target object, delegating to it, typically used for lazy loading and decoupling from target.

So your code sample looks like a *Proxy*.